# How to add spaces using div in HTML

Tags: html

I want to add spaces between two widgets. Please tell me an inline div code to add a space of around 300px. I have used this code:

```
<div style="width:300px"></div>
```

but I couldn't see 300px gap between the two widgets.

How to add this much gap between those widgets?

Comment: Margin:left:300px; ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example , if you are keeping the div empty you need to give it a height than only it will occupy the space .

```css
.div1{width:200px;background:#ddd;height:200px;display:inline-block}
.div2{width:200px;background:red;height:200px;display:inline-block}
.gap{width:200px;background:none;height:200px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class='div1'></div><div class='gap'></div><div class='div2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*edit: removed solution that had already been tried but was not yet in the question*

Pure HTML:

`<div>Link &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google.com</a></div>`

Note that `&nbsp;` represents a single space, so keep adding them until you have enough. Note that this is an extremely crude and not-recommended solution. For a pure CSS solution, see the demo.

*edit:* [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oveLjcrc/1/)

Comment: If i need to add &nbsp; then why there is a need of adding <div> In such case I need to put many &nbsp; I just want to add 300px space between two widgets in wordpress. I added a text widget and want to add that div code in order to get the right spacing.

Comment: Then use my first example in css? The second option was just for a pure-html solution. Alternatively just do `<div style="width:300px;"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, But as you can see in my question, I have written the same code. It's not working

Comment: @Kiru Great :) You may like to accept the answer as correct for future visitors. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

for me only margin tag helped. therefore it is my suggestion :

```
<div style="margin-left: 5px;">
```